# Шифр Цезаря, ASCII таблица

Tags: c++, шифрование

Читаю посимвольно строку , если нахожу символ "z" , хочу его превратить в символ "а", почему не работает?

```
for (i = 0; i < strlen(l); i++)
    {
        if (l[i] == char(122)) {
            l[i] == char(97);

        }
        l[i] += y;
    }
    cout << "\nЗакодированное сообщение:\n\n" << l << endl << endl;
```

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < strlen(l); i++)` означает, что `strlen` будет все время вычисляться при проверке условия. `for (i = 0, len = strlen(l); i < len; i++)` имхо получше вариант.

Comment: Ну и причем тут шифр Цезаря?...

Answer (score 4):

Это

```
l[i] == char(97)
```

сравнение, а не присваивание

```
l[i] = char(97)
```

И еще - вот такая запись (`char(97)`) только запутывает всех и вас смого. Пишите лучше символ непосредственно - `'A'`. Так куда понятнее.

Comment: Но это не единственная проблема кода из вопроса. Закикливание алфавита где?